# Match a single sample to a larger dataframe

Tags: r

this is the second time asking a similar question because i have not found the result i am looking for:
I have the following dataframe:

```
gene = c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k", "a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k", "a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k")
sample1 = c("a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a", "a","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c")
expression1 = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24","25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "36")
      
data_frame(gene, sample1, expression1)
```

and I have a following dataframe

```
gene = c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k")
sample2 = c("g","g","g","g","g","g","g","g","g","g","g")
expression2 = c("14.7", "15", "17", "16", "18", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25")
   gene  sample2 expression2
   <chr> <chr>   <chr>      
 1 a     g       14.7       
 2 b     g       15         
 3 c     g       17         
 4 d     g       16         
 5 e     g       18         
 6 f     g       20         
 7 g     g       21         
 8 h     g       22         
 9 i     g       23         
10 j     g       24         
11 k     g       25
```

and the result i am looking for is that I get a match between sample2 = g && sample1 = b, because they are most similar in gene expression. how Should I approach this.

it will look something like this:

```
   gene  sample2 expression2 sample1 expression1
   <chr> <chr>   <chr>       <chr>   <chr>      
 1 a     g       14.7        b       14         
 2 b     g       15          b       15         
 3 c     g       17          b       16         
 4 d     g       16          b       17         
 5 e     g       18          b       18         
 6 f     g       20          b       19         
 7 g     g       21          b       20         
 8 h     g       22          b       21         
 9 i     g       23          b       22         
10 j     g       24          b       23         
11 k     g       25          b       24
```

Comment: What do you mean "they are most similar in gene expression"? what is a numerical/programmatical way to say this?

Comment: why does roll nearest does not work here? cf. your previous question?

Comment: @Maël So, I want the sample to match based on gene expression between the 2 dataframes. But I do not know if they will be a full match between gene expression a, and gene expression b. so that is why I say most similar gene expressions between samples

Comment: @Maël my datasets were too big so my PC could not handle it. I thought I'd split up one dataframe to do it sample by sample in a for loop. but if u sall roll will work in this case also, I will do that.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, expression := as.numeric(expression1)]
setDT(df2)[, expression := as.numeric(expression2)]
df1[df2, on = .(gene, expression), roll = "nearest"][, expression := NULL][]

#     gene sample1 expression1 sample2 expression2
#  1:    a       b          14       g        14.7
#  2:    b       b          15       g          15
#  3:    c       b          16       g          17
#  4:    d       b          17       g          16
#  5:    e       b          18       g          18
#  6:    f       b          19       g          20
#  7:    g       b          20       g          21
#  8:    h       b          21       g          22
#  9:    i       b          22       g          23
# 10:    j       b          23       g          24
# 11:    k       b          24       g          25
```

Comment: this does indeed match. But it matches all the expression data individually and so it matches different samples of sample 1 to sample 2. and What I want is to just return me one sample out of sample 1 that matches closest to sample 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
df2 %>%
  right_join(df1, 'gene') %>%
  group_by(sample1)%>%
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE)%>%
  mutate(nrm = norm(expression1 - expression2, "2"))%>%
  ungroup()%>%
  filter(min(nrm) == nrm)%>%
  select(-nrm)

# A tibble: 11 × 5
   gene  sample2 expression2 sample1 expression1
   <chr> <chr>         <dbl> <chr>         <int>
 1 a     g              14.7 b                14
 2 b     g              15   b                15
 3 c     g              17   b                16
 4 d     g              16   b                17
 5 e     g              18   b                18
 6 f     g              20   b                19
 7 g     g              21   b                20
 8 h     g              22   b                21
 9 i     g              23   b                22
10 j     g              24   b                23
11 k     g              25   b                24
```